# How can I match data from a list to a column from an array?

Tags: r, genetics

I am very new to R, and this might be a silly question, but I appreciate any help in advance.

I have a large data frame named `df_long0` with a column titled `Gene.names`. I have another matrix titled `annotLookup` with two columns: `gene` and `ensembl`. I need to match `df_long0$Gene.names` with the Ensembl IDs from `annotLookup$ensemble`. I tried using the `match()` function, but I don't have enough experience to know what it meant or what to do with it.

Here is an example of what I have:

```
annotLookup
| gene | ensembl |
| -------- | ------------------ |
| Tslp     | ENSMUSG00000024379 |
| Pcsk9    | ENSMUSG00000034139 |

 df_long0
| Gene.names |
| ------- |
| Pcsk9   |
| Tslp    |
```

How can I match it up so I can add the `annotLookup$ensembl` column next to `df_long$Gene.names`?

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(head(YOURDATA)`. Edit your question and put the `structure`-output from `dput` into your question.